# How to dynamically update a label in Razor c#

Tags: label, razor-pages

How to add code in OnInitializedAsync to update the label?

```
<div id="container">
    <label id="labelId" class="label"></label>
</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // code to set the display text for the label here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <label id="labelId" class="label">@_labelText</label>
</div>

@code {
    private string _labelText;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _labelText = "This is a label.";
    }   
}
```

If you are not calling any async methods then you should use `OnInitialized` instead of `OnInitializedAsync`.